# VoIP Push Notification from Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I would like to use Parse for sending `VoIP push notifications`, but it seems that Parse doesn’t currently support it (I tried to add VoIP push notification certificate like common  push notification certificate, but parse return error

```
Unsupported certificate type. Common Name (CN) must contain one of: Apple Production IOS Push Services, Apple Development IOS Push Services, Pass Type ID, Apple Development Mac Push Services, Apple Production Mac Push Services.
```

May be I’m doing something wrong? Or, if it is really not supported now, may be there are some other approaches, maybe some external libraries that can be used in Parse Cloud Code?

Comment: Parse doesn't support PushKit VoIP certificates yet. We've waiting for that feature as well.

Answer (score 0):

Parse still not supported Voice over IP .
Below is the link describe you about Parse tutorials

https://parse.com/tutorials

or It you want parse text as push notification them refer below link:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/tree/master/iOS

But for sending push notification you have to attached push enable p.12 file in your parse account.